# How to solve this sed syntax issue

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I wrote a regex code to extract anchor tags from a html file and got this output.

```
mdlinks.txt
    <a href='/aspnet/aspnet_refhtmlcontrols.asp'>ASP.NET Reference</a>
    <a href='/aspnet/webpages_ref_classes.asp'>Razor Reference</a>
    <a href='/html/html_examples.asp'>HTML Examples</a>
    <a href='/css/css_examples.asp'>CSS Examples</a>
    <a href='/w3css/w3css_examples.asp'>W3.CSS Examples</a>
    <a href="/js/js_examples.asp" target="_top">JavaScript Examples</a>
    <a href="/js/js_dom_examples.asp" target="_top">HTML DOM Examples</a>
```

I have to represent the output as

"text to display" using the sed tool.

```
    <a[\s]href=('|")([^>]+)">((?:.(?!\<\/a\>))*.)<\/a>
```

This is my regex which captures the text and href link.

Here is the sed command i wrote

```
sed -E "s/\"<a[\s]href=('|\")([^>]+)\">((?:.(?!\<\/a\>))*.)<\/a>\"/\[\2\] \(\1\)/" mdlinks.txt
```

But this gives me error.
Can some please help me?

Comment: What error do you get?  And what does the desired output look like?

Comment: You're trying to use some regexp variant that isn't supported by sed or any other standard UNIX tool (maybe it's a PCRE? idk). Post a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: You can't use non-capturing groups `(?: )` with sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a job for regex (or any other string manipulation tool). You need tools able to parse html. An example using `xsltproc`:

1) install the `xsltproc` package (if needed)

2) Write this xsl file that describes how to transform the html input: `stylesheet.xsl`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version= "1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="//a">[<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>] (<xsl:value-of select="@href"/>)</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

3) Take your original file or your original html content in a variable (let's say "CONTENT"), but not mdlinks.txt (this step is useless and greping links in html content is error-prone and a waste of time *(at least 5 hours for you)*) and write:

```
xsltproc --html --novalid stylesheet.xsl <(echo "$CONTENT")
```

You obtain:

```
[Google.com] (http://google.com)
[An Example] (http://example.com/files.html)
[File #23] (file23.html)
[See my picture!] (images/mypic.png)
[Email Joel] (mailto:joelross@uw.edu)
```

Link: http://scott.dd.com.au/wiki/XSLT_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Parsing html with line oriented tools will normally fail. Given your simple layout, you could try

```
tr -s "<" ">" < mdlinks.txt | cut -d">" -f3
```